# Storing Lyrics in a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I wanted to know what is the best way of storing music "Lyrics" in a mysql database. and what are the setting used for that. Also, i would like the table to store the break lines.

I was thinking about using "|" to indicate a new line and using php to replace string.

I have no idea where to start, or what to use for the parameters (varchar, int (i know it's not going to be int), etc.)

Currently, I have my tracks table laid out like this

```
table tracks
----
id (int, 10, primary key)
albumid (foreign key to albums table)
name (varchar, 50)
override_artist (overrides album artist if not null)
playtime (int, 5)
lyric (??????)
```

Any ideas would be awesome.

Comment: Easiest way is to use a `text`. It will also store your linebreaks fine, so no need to convert them.

Comment: Storing them is the easy part. How do you want to **use** them once they are stored (e.g. do you need to search on each line prefix, or perhaps on individual words, do you need to modify them etc...)? Anticipated usage often drives the database model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your lyric column should be the [`TEXT` type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html), and you should probably store it in a separate MyISAM table keyed to the `tracks` table if your `tracks` table uses the InnoDB engine (which new installs do by default).  This will enable you to do full text searches over the TEXT column:

Table lyrics:

```
CREATE TABLE lyric (
  lyricid INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  /* foreign key to tracks.id */
  trackid INT,
  lyric TEXT,
  FOREIGN KEY (trackid) REFERENCES tracks (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

You can simply store the linebreaks in the lyrics as plain old line breaks. You don't need to replace them in the database. Instead, in your output to HTML, you would convert them to `<br />` (in PHP, that's done with `nl2br()`).  In other words, if you enter text into the database that has linebreaks, don't treat them specially at all. They'll work fine.

Comment: Awesome stuff, Thanks for the reply. This really helped out with my problem. I never knew about nl2br(), I'll have to look at the php page on how to properly use that function. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I would choose a `TEXT` column and store the newlines just as they are - this is perfectly valid in a MySQL table.