# Storing lyrics in a SQL Server database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Basically, the exact same question as this:

[Storing Lyrics in a MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350629/storing-lyrics-in-a-mysql-database)

except I'm using SQL Server with a C# / asp.net front end.  I don't need them searchable, I just want to retrieve them and have them formatted (i.e. line breaks) properly when displayed.

Comment: Line breaks can be stored in SQL Server. Have you had an issue with storing (or retrieving) them?

Comment: So, basically the same answer, just instead of `Text` use `varchar` or `nvarchar`, Try not to use `[n]varchar(max)` if you don't have to.

Comment: LOL.  Not laughing at anyone in particular, it's just funny that one person said not to use nvarchar(max) at almost the exact same time as someone else said to use it.

Comment: I think nvarchar allows for (more) language-accents so go with that. Someone correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: @JohnnyBones [n]varchar(max) comes with a performance penalty in a lot of cases. as a rule of thumb, it's best to avoid allowing data to be way longer then it should. I see all the time stuff like `userName nvarchar(max)` when in reality, 99.9% of user names are shorter than 20 chars.

Comment: @ZoharPeled - I hear that.  I used to be in a data warehouse, and it's been so long that I've forgotten much more than I'll ever relearn.  I do recall, however, when we were dealing with tables in excess of 2B records that (max) in general was bad, and every bit we could save mattered.

Answer (score 1):

Just store as nvarchar(max) data type.

Note, if you pull the column out with SSMS, it won't have formatting (SSMS itself strips all CR/LFs), but if you extract it with C#, it will be retained exactly as it went in, and you can display as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Create your table as usual

```
 CREATE TABLE [ExampleName] (id int primary key
                                /*your other values...*/
                                ,lyric nvarchar(max))
```

and then you just save the lyrics in there depending on how you handle database access.